# Snowflake Show Database Result

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can we iterate over the output of the query `show databases` in snowflake using JDBC. If there is another way to check if database is present or not over jdbc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requirement is for validating the list of DB's and use it for some kind of audit purpose, you may can do the following:

1. First run the following command:

   **show databases;**
2. Then use the result_scan() function to get the DB name and the owner from the result of the previous command:

   **select $2 as DB_NAME, $6 as DB_OWNER from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));**
3. This list can be stored in new database table which is given access for other roles to check and validate.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like:

```
select distinct database_name from information_schema.databases;
```

Comment: It doesn't return all database, it return only those whose owner is current role